# How does Date.toLocaleDateString() work?

Tags: javascript, date, configuration, locale, date-format

I've to represent the date with local user's configurations. Follows the **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)** description:

> The toLocaleDateString method relies on the underlying operating
>   system in formatting dates. It converts the date to a string using the
>   formatting convention of the operating system where the script is
>   running. For example, in the United States, the month appears before
>   the date (04/15/98), whereas in Germany the date appears before the
>   month (15.04.98).

I do this:

```
var date = new Date ();
console.log (date.toLocaleDateString ());
```

It prints out `Saturday, October 13, 2012` but what I expect is `Sabato, 13 Ottobre, 2012` (that's the Italian date format).
Now, configurations of my browser and my system are set properly (Italian language and the above format date) so I don't understand how does `toLocaleDateString` work.

**Am I doing it right?**

Comment: are you sure you've entered `toLocaleDateString` and not `toLocaleString`?

Comment: All the specification is saying is that it is *implementation-dependent*: http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.5.6 (and that it is intended to represent the date in the current locale, but well, it's just that, intended).

Comment: @artistoex both Firefox (16) and Chromium (18). The system is Ubuntu (11.10)

Comment: MDN doesn't seem to be too correct there. For Chrome, the [source](http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/date.js#232) shows that it simply uses hardcoded, English names for days/months. There is no check for the current locale.

Comment: Well, I leave this question open so if things change, someone (or me) can post the solution.
What a pity, `toLocaleDateString` would have been an interesting implementation of local date.

Comment: works in FF for me ... just used 2 days ago, Win XP, correct set locale ... FF is in English ... check these notes here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Comment: @Reflective Works either for me in English but not in Italian or for other languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is out-of-date.

These are my tests:

```
(new Date ()).toLocaleDateString () -> "4/9/2013" (italian format 'd/m/Y') with Chrome 29
(new Date ()).toLocaleDateString () -> "mercoledì 4 settembre 2013" (italian format 'D d M Y') with Firefox 22
```

It works with newest browsers versions.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Mozilla documentation, the format can vary wildly depending on the user's location and computer settings.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

The exact format depends on the platform, locale and user's settings.