# Is there a clean jQuery method of increasing a datepicker field by one day using blur event?

Tags: date, datepicker, increment, blur, document-ready

My code works, but it throws the NaN 'not a number' before updating the field correctly. Im just being nit picky for efficiency as the 2nd field is going to be a hidden administration field as this is to fix a bug where a CRM is subtracting minus one day for some unknown reason when syncing with gravity forms to agilecrm, so I need to push the +1 date instead.

Here's my code. As I said, it works, but I wonder if there's a cleaner pure jQuery method without crossing back and forth between javascript. Although other solutions with javascript could be useful.  I know I could possibly put some kind of if not (!datepicker) logic somewhere, but need the syntax and best practice do it.

Reason for asking:  The answer in multiple places was to just use:

```
    newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 1);
```

However this answer was not working until I found the additional concatenating setup to put together the final mm/dd/yyyy format to resolve, also I didn't see a good jQuery on document.ready listening for a blur event solution to update another dated field in any other article so figure this would be worth the time to have discussed.

Also [here's a link](http://www.generationsavon.com/hall/datefix-mod/) to the page with the form and the fixdate field that's populated.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#input_6_4").blur(function(){


var tt = $("#input_6_4").val(); 

//alert(tt);

var date = new Date(tt);
var newdate = new Date(date);

newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 1);

var dd = newdate.getDate();
var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
var y = newdate.getFullYear();

var FixDate = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + y;

// alert(FixDate);

$("#input_6_14").attr('value',FixDate);

    });
});

</script>
```

[Megalayer: Complete End to End Managed Website Solutions](http://www.megalayer.com)

Comment: There are too many ajax calls are going on your first date field blur event? may I know why is that?

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to.  Do you mean how I made it a nested function?  I know it's not correct, just I got it working and wanted the right solution as I learn to code more cleanly.  Your answer below fixes another issue I noticed regarding if the user chooses the last day of the month the script doesn't increment the month.  I had started to code a complex set of nested if(then) arguments.   How is yours handling that?  I don't see where or how it's being resolved to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the optimized code for your code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#input_6_4").blur(function(){

  var newdate = new Date(this.value);
  newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 1);
  $("#input_6_14").val(newdate.toLocaleDateString());

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Old Date: <input id="input_6_4" / value="5/20/2015"> 
<br/>
<br/>
New Date: <input id="input_6_14" />
```

Comment: It appears that the javascript function:
toLocaleDateString |
was the power answer for legitimately adding a specific number of days to a pre-existing variable holding a mm/dd/yyy date value. (aside from intricacies of toLocaleDateString's return response 

Thanks @vinayakj

Comment: Worth referring to this for others whom will have futher formatting concerns as we always do when working with date formatting:  

[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871611/how-does-date-tolocaledatestring-work[/link]StackOverflow: How does Date.toLocaleDateString() work?